# Order details do not load

Tags: opencart

Shipping Method & Payment Method doesn't show at all but after I click **Update Tools** button it shows up. When I check the script it's called and loaded via AJAX.

Login to admin panel. Go to Sales > Orders > Click **edit** an order > Click **Totals** tab. Look at **Order Details** table below.

Here's a screenshot before I click **Update Tools** 
[image: Before Click Update Tools Button]

And after I click on **Update Tools**
[image]

Here's the script which shows selectbox

```
<select name="payment">
    <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
    <?php if ($payment_code) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $payment_code; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $payment_method; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

It seems `$payment_code` doesn't contain any loop that's why it doesn't seem to load all before I click the button.

The question is: Is it correct or is it a bug?

**Did anyone ever take a look at payment and shipping method loading at all without clicking on "Update Tools" button?**

I have compared with original script and the script is exactly the same.

Opencart Version: 1.5.6

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, it shouldn't be a loop. `$payment_code` and `$payment_method` aren't arrays, they just contain one entry (the order's current payment method). Have a look at the getForm() method in the sale/order controller to confirm:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['payment_code'])) {
    $this->data['payment_code'] = $this->request->post['payment_code'];
} elseif (!empty($order_info)) {
    $this->data['payment_code'] = $order_info['payment_code'];
} else {
    $this->data['payment_code'] = '';
}
```

This has been a headache a few times for some of my clients. I believe it's because it doesn't bother to calculate all relevant shipping methods in case you change the address. Ideally it should, and would recalculate when you change zone, but it doesn't, so... there ya go! Not a bug, just not ideal functionality.

Comment: So, what should I do when I want to select different payment method? It's only show payment method which I have selected?

Comment: Hit the "update totals" button as you have been doing